# How to Get available space on windows phone Using Windows portable devices services apis?

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, winapi, wpd

How to findout available space in windows phone (mtp device) using windows portable devices api. I have implemented WPD api to transfer media files to and from windows phone. But now, i need to calculate available space on the device. I have gone through whole documentation of wpd. Documentation says that to findout device related properties like available space or battery level, WPD's STATUS_SERVICE should be implemented (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpdblog/archive/2009/08/15/introducing-device-services.aspx). Real question is that, how can i implement that service and from where i can get any sample working program (if it exists)? If anyone have some helping information, then guide me on right track. Thanks